# Remove second line where first few columns identical in large file

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
A 1 abc
A 1 def
A 2 ttt
B 2 ppp
B 2 qqq
```

I'd like to keep the first line when the first two keys are identical, so something like this:

```
A 1 abc
A 2 ttt
B 2 ppp
```

I found a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950882/remove-lines-when-three-columns-are-identical) that solved this. However, my file is 1.2 GB, and I'm matching on the first 19 columns. So when I run this:

```
  awk  '!array[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19]++' infile > outfile
```

I get this:

```
cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=infile FNR=287807) fatal: dupnode: r->stptr: can't allocate memory (Not enough memory)
```

Obviously I can't break the file apart to process because I don't know where the duplicates are. I'm willing to trade speed for memory to solve this. (The file is about 1.6 million lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your file seems to be sorted:

```
sort -m -u -k 1,2 < file
```

`-m` for *merge* doesn't attempt to sort the file, but with `-u` (for *unique*) combined with `-k 1,2` to specify a sort key consisting of the first 2 fields (use `-k 1,19` for the first 19 fields), we're removing duplicates on the first 2 fields.

If the file isn't sorted (at least on those 2 fields), then just drop the `-m`. The result will end up being sorted though. The sorting will be expensive, but it should be OK memory wise as `sort` resorts to using temporary files for sorting big files (you need free disk space on `/tmp` (or `$TMPDIR`)).

Comment: For my purposes, the file isn't really sorted. `sort` seems to complain after 2 fields; when I do `-k 1,2,3,4` (all the way to 19), it gives me `invalid field specification` (in fact, it complains at 1,2,3)

Comment: @innocentunremarkable, it's `-k1,19` for fields 1 to 19 (for the portion of the line that starts at the first field and ends with the 19th field)

Answer (score 0):

Will combining the columns that are identical to form an index work ? With your above eg. we could do --

```
 awk '{ind=""; for(i=1; i<3; i++) {ind=ind" "$i }  if (!arr[ind]) arr[ind]=$3  } END{for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}'

  A 1 abc
  A 2 ttt
  B 2 ppp
```

you will of course need to change the loop above to combine the indices you need.

Answer (score 0):

For future occasions, you can do so.. and you save the problem of giant files with arrays. Each time the field one changes its value, the array is deleted.

```
BEGIN{
    xd=""; 
}
{
    id=$1;

    if (id != xd)
    {
        for (x in arr)
        {
            print x,arr[x];
        }

        delete arr; #Each time the field one changes its value
        xd=id;
    }
    ind="";
    for (i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
        ind=ind $i;
    }
    if (!arr[ind])
    {
        arr[ind]=$3;
    }

}

END {
        for (x in arr)
        {
            print x,arr[x];
        }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.txt
A1 abc
A2 ttt
B2 ppp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
awk '_a[$1" "$2]++==0'  < filename
```